# Parsing the output of /proc/net/dev with awk and dismissing the first two lines

Tags: parsing, awk

This command gives me the following output:

```
 cat /proc/net/dev | awk '{print $1}'
 Inter-|
 face
 eth0:
 lo:
 wlan0:
```

Is there a way to dismiss the lines inter-|, face so i can get only the names of the interfaces?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tweaking your awk a little bit:

```
awk 'NR>2{print $1}' /proc/net/dev
```

Answer (score 4):

```
tail -n +3 /proc/net/dev | awk...
```

`tail -n {+whatever}` (note the plus sign) can be used to dump files starting from the nth line.

Comment: You'll want to use +3, not 2 in that case, otherwise you'll still get the line `face`, at least I do (Ubuntu 12.04).

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing this. If you just need it work for that specific case I'd do something simple like this:

```
cat /proc/net/dev | awk '{print $1}' | sed -e '1,2d'
```

Sed '1,2d' just means delete lines 1 and 2.

Comment: How is that simple??? You're using 3 commands and 2 pipes when one trivial command wild do, see the answer from @Guru.

Comment: @EdMorton It's simple, because he's already using two of them. Adding "sed -e '1,2d'" to a string you already have *IS* simple. And for the record I've already seen Guru's answer and I like it. So what? It invalidates nothing of what I said, 3 question-marks or not.

Comment: Ah, I see, so you meant a simple update vs a simple solution. got it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers:

just in case you don't want to use `awk` with `tail`, you can do also this:

```
tail -n +3 /proc/net/dev | cut -d':' -f1
```